# How to make angular waiting for load session info data from the server?

Tags: angularjs

I have session info on the server and it uses in many controllers of my app. How can I make an angular wait until session load at startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use a loading bar or something like that.

**Loading bar:** http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/

Beasides, you may create a angular service (for e.g. SessionService) which returns a promise for Session data from the server.

Finally, inside the angujar's run method do this:
1 - Start the loading bar.
2 - Call your angular session service.
3 - Once the session service promise was resolved stop the loading bar.

Example:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).

  run(function() {

   startLoadingBar();

   callService.then(function(){
      stopLoadingBar();
   });

});
```

I hope it helps.